# Rust Sorting Algorithm

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a sorting algorithm in Rust, but am getting this error (The algorithm is still incomplete):

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `new_list` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/exercises/mode_and_median.rs:35:13
   |
28 |     for &i in &new_list {
   |               ---------
   |               |
   |               immutable borrow occurs here
   |               immutable borrow later used here
...
35 |             new_list[index] = new_list[index + 1];
   |             ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `new_list` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/exercises/mode_and_median.rs:36:13
   |
28 |     for &i in &new_list {
   |               ---------
   |               |
   |               immutable borrow occurs here
   |               immutable borrow later used here
...
36 |             new_list[index + 1] = temp;
   |             ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `learning` (bin "learning") due to 2 previous errors
```

Code:

```
fn sort(list: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    let mut new_list = list.clone();
    
    for &i in &new_list {
        let index = new_list.iter().position(|&x| x == i).unwrap();
        let next_item = new_list.get(index + 1).unwrap();
        if i > *next_item {
            //swap places
            //x = y; y = z; z = x;
            let temp = new_list[index];
            new_list[index] = new_list[index + 1];
            new_list[index + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    return new_list;
}
```

I tried changing new_list to an immutable reference from moving. Didn't help.

Comment: Hint: Instead of iterating the items and then searching for their index. You could instead just iterate all indices, e.g. `for i in 0..new_list.len()`. That will at least resolve your borrow issue. Whether that fits your algorithm, is something else

Comment: You are modifying the array in the conditional at the same time as holding a mutable reference to it to iterate over it which is forbidden by Rust's borrow rules. Check out @vallentin to fix this. There are other issues with your implementation though, but this will "fix" the compiler error.

Comment: Also, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html is going to be your friend. Swap can't be implemented the way you have in safe rust without tripping the borrow checker.

Comment: Here you can find a rust implementation of bubble sort: https://gist.github.com/rylev/be8bdfe62a2fe45d3837551531af96ab

Comment: @user1937198 For slices it's [`<[T]>::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap), which also can't be implemented in safe code (neither with `mem::swap()`).

Comment: Also, a recommendation: since sorting doesn't modify the number of elements, it will be better to take `&mut [f32]` (or even a generic `&mut [T]`) than `&Vec<f32>` (which [really should be replaced by `&[f32]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/7884305)) and return `Vec<f32>`. This way, callers can sort the data in-place, without copying it, and copying is still as easy as `let mut b = a.clone(); sort(&mut b);`.